# Test data generator for typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for something like Autofixture for C#.

For those that don't know Autofixture is most often used when writing tests, it lets you specify a class and it will return an instance of that class with randomised properties.

Does something like this exist for typescript?

I've found a few packages such as [autofixture](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autofixture) and [ts-autofixture](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-autofixture) but I'm new to typescript so I just wanted to hear from the community.

Comment: I was looking for something similar and found this: https://github.com/danibram/mocker-data-generator and: https://www.npmjs.com/package/factory.ts

Comment: https://github.com/willryan/factory.ts looks quite similar